# Why are all forms submitted when only one form's submit button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, button

I have two forms that go to different places/serve different purposes, but co-exist in a popup window. Only one is intended to be used at a time. The first form's button submits only itself (correctly), but the second form's button submits both:

form.html

```
<div>
    <form id="form1" action="/onePlace" method="post">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      <!-- Submits form1 -->
    </form>

    <form id="form2" action="/anotherPlace" method="post">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      <!-- Submits form1 and form2 -->
    </form>
</div>
```

loaded into another page

```
<div id="loadedForm"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Event fires to reveal in modular dialogue
    function(){
        $('#loadedForm').load('/form'); // Server serves form.html
        $("#promptLoginSignup").lightbox_me({
            centered: true,
            onLoad: function () {
                $(function() {
                    $('#form1').submit(function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        console.log('form1 submitted'); // Fires on both button presses
                    });
                    $('#form2').submit(function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        console.log('form2 submitted'); // Fires only on second button press
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

**Edit**: More accurately represents my actual code and describes the setup in more detail.

**Edit 2 Clarification**: This problem exists on a web server and uses resources from said server. It cannot be reproduced in a snippet or a pen. Simply pointing out the fact that it isn't reproducible on the page is not helpful, obviously this is not something that can actually be done on a single page and could not be held to the same scrutiny of "complete" code samples. I am giving you as much as possible and only asking for any insight that could be provided by those who may have some and not those without any.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, see snippet.

Comment: Did you forget to close the `<form>` tag of the first form? This example you posted works as expected.

Comment: Nope, the form tag is properly closed. Event tried adding redundant closing tags to be sure.

Comment: Maybe you should include some of your actual code, because the issue doesn't exist in your example.

Comment: Can't for many reasons. Work is for a client and contains sensitive info but is basically identical sans the input fields. It's loaded from another page on a shared domain, so it's not really possible to demonstrate as a snippet. Boo to the downvoters with juvenile patience

Comment: The scenario you are descripting is impossible given the code you have provided. This question is therefore unclear and not answerable without assuming the code you provided is inaccurate.

Comment: Have a read of [mcve] - the emphasis here on *reproducible*.  You asked a clean question and provided some code - but the code does not reproduce the problem.  So it's anyone's guess what *else* will be causing the problem unless you can tell us what other code you have - ie something not in the question.  Hence the downvotes.

Comment: No, both forms have 2 inputs. One is log in, on is sign up. I guess this is too complicated for SO. It is loaded using the lightbox_me jQuery plugin using jQuery's .load() as a separate html resource, as a triggered event at the end of a video's playback. I am very doubtful any of that could cause the problem. I am using jQuery 3.3.1 if that makes a difference. 

I am listening for the submit event so not sure type=button would work. It's always worked with one form. Adding the second is problematic

Comment: What is the exact symptom you're seeing? You're getting two log messages when you click the second submit button?

Comment: If you can't show us code that reproduces the problem, it's really hard for us to debug it. It's not like this is a common problem we can easily recognize.

Comment: @Barmar yes. It makes absolutely no sense to me

Comment: What browser are you using? IE doesn't (or didn't) support multiple FORMS on one page with multiple submit buttons. That's really not a good practice IMHO.

Comment: @mrunion Can you provide a reference for that? Multiple forms have been common for many years. Thousands of web sites have a landing page with both login and register forms, just like he's trying to do.

Comment: Make sure form2 isn't nested inside form1. That's not valid HTML, but if the browser accepts it you could get this problem because of event bubbling.

Comment: I have no specific reference. In HTML 4.01 having multiple forms with the same "name" attribute was undefined. I do recall that it wasn't IE that had a problem with it -- that was a mistaken memory -- it was early versions of Dot Net that freaked out when it tried to place the state in the special form element. But seeing that this is not Dot Net my point is moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not reproduced but one thing you might check is if the second submit button container overrides the first one, to avoid submitting both try adding `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Worked like a charm! I still don't fully understand what the issue is and why this fixed it, but it works exactly as expected by adding this line.

Comment: You should still look for the underlying problem. This just stops the event propagation.